# Android: activity managment and NFC Tag detector

Tags: android, android-activity, nfc

I hope that someone can help me with this.

As you know when an NFC tag is detected automatically we have a window dialog that contains the list the application that we can use. To avoid this there is a way with pending event to intercept the tag and avoid the window dialog with the list.

**My problem:**
I have a `TabActivity` with two activities. 
One of the two activities read a tag (we can call this activity as follow: "**READ_ACTIVITY**").
When a tag is detected I don't want change my screen, I want to stay in the same interface where I am before the interception of the tag. 
As I said it's possible to do it with the following code:

```
      mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(hereiam, intent, null, null);
```

where intent is a pendingIntent.

Now this foreground dispatch is done by **READ_ACTIVITY**.
My problem is that when a tag is detect, the application open a new READ ACTIVITY, while I would like to stay in the `tabactivity`. Someone knows how to stay in the `tabactivity` when a tag is detected?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the TechList that you wanna intercept and also the intentFiltersArray, please follow the [documentation about this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html#foreground-dispatch), as well as the NFC and API demos samples, the already implement what you want.